# Cannot get an absolute import to work with python 3.7.0

Tags: python, import, parent, sys

I have a root folder called dumdum which contains an **init** and a folder called foo. Within foo are an **ini** and two modules, foo1 and foo6.

```
dumdum/

       __init__
       foo/

              __init__
              foo1
              foo6
```

I want foo6 to work when called on its own and when a main module in the root folder dumdum calls it, so I have been trying to work out how to get foo6 to work in all cases, i.e. I want foo6 to work on its own and when it is not the main file. I run foo6 from an IDE.
Foo6 calls foo1, but when I do that I get an error :

ModuleNotFoundError no folder named 'foo'

As foo is the parent folder for both foo1 and foo6 I can't understand why this is happening.

**foo1.py:**

```
def printy(msg):
    print(msg)


def printing_mystr(mystr):
    printy(mystr)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(__name__)
    printing_mystr(r"I am a string in foo_1")
```

**foo6.py**

```
import sys, pathlib
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # if foo is the root folder
    print(os.getcwd())
    print(str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent))
    sys.path.append(str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent))
    #for i in sys.path:
        #print(i)
    
    from foo.foo1 import printy, printing_mystr


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(__name__)
    printing_mystr("Oh I am a string passed into foo_1")
```

when I run:

```
import sys

for i in sys.path:
    print(i)
```

I get:

```
    C:\Users\priper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python37.zip
C:\Users\priper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs
C:\Users\priper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib
C:\Users\priper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37
C:\Users\priper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages

    C:\Users\priper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\Users\priper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Users\priper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\
C:\Users\priper\Desktop\dumdum\foo
```

**Traceback**

ModuleNotFoundError no module named 'foo'
in foo6.py...Line 12

Comment: You probably don't have your python path setup correctly.   you don't mention what that looks like nor what directory and command line you are using to invoke the modules.   please add those to the question.

Comment: I run all my code from an IDE, the root folder dumdum is just on the desktop. I have edited the question but im not 100% I am answering your question to be honest.

Comment: I think you need `C:\Users\priper\Desktop\dumdum` in your `sys.path` in order to import `foo` and `foo.foo1`.

Comment: @nechoj, that works, could you put it as an answer and explain briefly why that has to be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When importing modules without any further path information you need to have the path directly beneath the module location as a member of `sys.path`. In your case, add `C:\Users\priper\Desktop\dumdum` to `sys.path`.

If you start the python program inside the folder `dumdum\foo\foo6`, then `os.getcwd()` would give you `dumdum\foo\foo6`. Therefore, your import `from foo.foo1 import printy, printing_mystr` won't work. Even adding `pathlib.Path(__file__).parent` is not enough, because this is `dumdum\foo` and not `\dumdum` as it should be.